# People Picker showing same user twice in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, fba, peoplepicker

First of all I am new to SP 2010 FBA.

Please see the below scenario;

I created a web app which supports both FBA and Windows authentication. Then I created some users using the MemberShip Seeder tool in this web app. Now on I search the user using people picker the same user is appearing twice. One in upper case and the other in lower case. Whichever user I am clicking/selecting the exact user is only getting added. The issue is appearing only if I am searching with lower case. If I am entering names with uppercase letters, then everything is working fine.

So please anyone, provide your suggestions to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue while using Claims authentication.

On close inspection I found that the returned duplicate results were having different login names. For example if one result was `ads\john` then the other one was `i:0#.w|ads\john`.

It is easy to remove such duplicates if you are programming against server side directly with the following API code:

```
private string GetLoginName(string name)
{
     var manager = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
     if (manager != null)
     {
         return SPClaimProviderManager.IsEncodedClaim(name) ? manager.DecodeClaim(name).Value : name;
     }
     return name;
}
```

I have blogged about it here:

http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2014/01/29/convert-claim-based-login-name.html

Comment: Thanks Madhur, Thanks for the reply,

But in our situation we are having only FBA users and the login ids are same for the displayed users in the people picker search dialog. The only issue is the name is appearing twice in the people picker in both lower and upper cases. Please share your thoughts

Comment: Please check out data store containing your users list. Is the data store SQL server ?

Comment: Yes, We are using SQL Server 2008 and there is no duplicate entry for these users

Comment: Have you customized any module ? Login etc. If yes, please post the code

Comment: We have put a custom login page. But in that case we were simply using the Sharepoint Login control to login.